# fullcalendar, how to set the timeline view to start at a certain hour?

Tags: fullcalendar-4

The timeline at the moment is set to render days and hours. I would like to tell the timeline view to start at a certain hour, how can I do it ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Dani

Comment: To make my question more accurate, at the moment, the timeline view axis(day/time), goes from midnight to midnight, but I would like it start instead from a certain hour, e.g. to start at 19:00...
Any hint ? Thanks...

Comment: Has anyone an idea, where beside this place I could get help for fullcalendar issues ?

Thanks